# How often does Google re-calculate the page rank of webpage?

Tags: seo, pagerank

Am updating my website Backlinks and content from last 2 month but page rank is not changing,how often does Google re-calculate the page rank?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nobody knows except several Google engineers. Whatever, this PageRank notion is nowadays totally useless, please forget it.

Comment: PageRank in reference to the entire site, should be dropped from our vernacular. SiteRank is a better term, but the Google PageRank referring to SiteRank has lost value as the emphasis has shifted to the PageRank of individual pages. Even then, why chase the PageRank of individual pages? Just do what you do and worry about traffic. The rest will follow. I agree that PageRank however you define it, is a false God. It is important, but only to mature sites and only after all the hard work is done. Focus on PageRank is a distraction that should be avoided while churning and burning a new site.